# Table error not showing for dynamic DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dynamic datagrid which I am building in code and is rendering using the following

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable.DataList}"  AutoGenerateColumns="true"/>
```

I do the following to populate the grid:

```
public DataTableViewModel()
{
    DataList = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = typeof(string);
        column.ColumnName = "Header " + i;
        DataList.Columns.Add(column);
    }

    var row0 = DataList.NewRow();
    row0["Header " + 0] = "Object A - Value 1";
    row0["Header " + 1] = "Object A - Value 2";
    row0["Header " + 2] = "Object A - Value 3";
    DataList.Rows.Add(row0);

    var row1 = DataList.NewRow();
    row1["Header " + 0] =  "Object B - Value 1" ;
    row1["Header " + 1] =  "Object B - Value 2" ;
    row1["Header " + 2] =  "Object B - Value 3" ;
    DataList.Rows.Add(row1);

    DataList.ColumnChanged += DataList_ColumnChanged;
}

private void DataList_ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.RowError = "Row error!";
    e.Row.SetColumnError(e.Column, "Oh no!");
}
```

The data is displayed correctly, but I can not the the errors to work. I expect that when I edit one of the cells that it should show an error, but it does not. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why?

Because the `DataRow` doesn't implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface.

You could use a `ValidationRule` to display the error(s):

```
public class RowDataValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (value as BindingGroup).Items[0] as DataRowView;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(drv.Row.RowError))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, drv.Row.RowError);
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"  AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
        <local:RowDataValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
    </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
</DataGrid>
```

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-implement-validation-with-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for more information and samples.